# Gausian Mixture Model Throwing Error: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm trying to figure out a way to plot only the top 10 'importances'.  How can I filter out only the top 10?

I'm testing this code.

```
# Import matplotlib for plotting and use magic command for Jupyter Notebooks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline
# Set the style
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
# list of x locations for plotting
x_values = list(range(len(importances)))
# Make a bar chart
plt.bar(x_values, importances, orientation = 'vertical')
# Tick labels for x axis
plt.xticks(x_values, feature_list, rotation='vertical')
# Axis labels and title
plt.ylabel('Importance'); plt.xlabel('Variable'); plt.title('Variable Importances')
```

For example, I thought it would work like this:

```
importances.nlargest(10)
```

Of course, that didn't work.

Anyway, if I print 'importances', I get this.

```
[0.014491770647044457,
 0.00019361234623574235,
 3.1654130115528675e-05,
 2.2282968409838985e-09,
 3.2692807408152015e-09,
 4.384096695290309e-10,
 0.00042439694271008773,
 5.237777494120531e-07,
 0.001811981822169592,
 8.763153025774294e-05,
 0.0006285414711295239,
 0.0019943872516235126,
 0.008064958626964689,
 1.5713284855142127e-09,
 3.4880330238871455e-07,
 9.569576607849658e-08,
 4.905092782324521e-07,
 3.04975913750217e-08,
 0.0007710174613522453,
 0.010110214591790158,
 2.218810309666371e-06,
 0.06635437174813848,
 7.094141851738553e-09,
 0.09692579151784199,
 6.266476641239394e-07,
 0.0005677407074106191,
 4.33439485665928e-09,
 6.729704013292786e-09,
 5.448251307127653e-09,
 0.07222976995890511,
 4.177476454941959e-09,
 0.06379521041327217,
 4.143632970341204e-08,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 1.6852849006394362e-07,
 3.444763728488421e-05,
 0.00027783757981549023,
 0.00026552081342128665,
 0.0027951966216271645,
 1.756238666420933e-08,
 5.36418731927759e-07,
 1.8587336907357295e-08,
 1.724316065593696e-06,
 4.8075445998997775e-09,
 5.0946253981707984e-09,
 2.4109672351066337e-09,
 6.122816335970093e-07,
 2.98653718456776e-08,
 1.440685077013712e-08,
 3.4814858022082307e-07,
 4.9143061686861475e-09,
 5.560563276141058e-09,
 2.100160313340503e-07,
 1.858585731919769e-07,
 2.9302956455099447e-10,
 1.0676724849696455e-07,
 9.205202160096533e-08,
 3.238590336881132e-09,
 2.9359031523272006e-09,
 3.7106613254445946e-08,
 0.0,
 7.50949849787628e-09,
 4.31454496750231e-07,
 2.864722788138877e-09,
 0.00029555925564843296,
 0.018288095727344335,
 2.3235414188992915e-05,
 1.4724817163996177e-06,
 1.83332179664834e-10,
 6.5835933557009485e-09,
 3.4995919613648777e-08,
 1.5791218246276666e-09,
 8.543955452925974e-10,
 0.0020876600982017773,
 1.3271736183875074e-06,
 7.097092415371366e-09,
 1.1362350498921358e-06,
 2.596444953750965e-07,
 3.136898750550819e-06,
 0.006061284819096849,
 1.5073623701901606e-08,
 0.0,
 3.310508863330544e-10,
 4.012406143727027e-07,
 3.88598894478961e-10,
 7.25246298208171e-09,
 2.8319415813159036e-07,
 2.7331184262991413e-08,
 3.833752596597012e-09,
 8.11433296197117e-09,
 4.724264918239267e-09,
 2.8950794365442764e-10,
 3.507963799042248e-09,
 1.5810463846782645e-06,
 3.1443812975880694e-08,
 2.2369371106304586e-08,
 5.175362771499234e-10,
 1.2536062933757747e-07,
 1.7255185496828274e-08,
 3.530020584895972e-10,
 0.0,
 6.824913713173602e-06,
 6.614160172490679e-09,
 5.8441361773804216e-09,
 3.107053566891105e-08,
 1.1887553210153202e-08,
 1.2147831771421017e-07,
 3.847667195219461e-07,
 2.0541139213845712e-07,
 6.367649972302635e-09,
 0.0,
 8.713550587152909e-09,
 3.348791245078586e-09,
 1.249743894834997e-07,
 5.024591836321825e-09,
 1.1549722525405656e-08,
 1.5720375103778552e-09,
 1.2061111951654133e-08,
 2.204145040115562e-08,
 2.6538371008326488e-08,
 0.006065658473388039,
 1.1261253606401625e-06,
 5.3923623114030854e-08,
 2.7369694426362433e-08,
 2.2715623613698112e-09,
 3.267124083622971e-10,
 1.3555578552793559e-07,
 0.22123522867842335,
 1.6121802470302185e-07,
 1.0320822141246487e-07,
 0.0,
 0.00035559600865403307,
 5.69666004152515e-09,
 8.823972002649428e-09,
 1.2623398120425045e-09,
 0.1203515135510421,
 9.257687093715026e-09,
 0.07956702616209582,
 6.049395726141352e-08,
 0.13345147135296895,
 0.06792857593399991,
 4.0075569777901097e-07,
 0.0003016270514924225,
 0.000212157530509232,
 4.872071522305804e-07,
 0.0018899382796283444,
 1.8345580575407573e-08]
```

The concept is from this link.

https://towardsdatascience.com/random-forest-in-python-24d0893d51c0

Comment: It's a little bit hard to show everything.  I posted the link where I got the code from.  All I did was substitute that sample data for my own, and everything works fine, up to the point that I described in my post.

Comment: sorted(importances,reverse=True)[:10]

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks so much!!

Comment: I'll just post this as an answer to help whoever else sees this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`sorted(importances,reverse=True)[:10]`